# Is there any way, a software can access hidden files in Ubuntu, without renaming files?

Tags: eclipse, github, ubuntu-18.04, git-clone, bndtools

I am trying to clone [openEMS](https://github.com/OpenEMS/openems) repository and *import* it in Eclipse's Bndtools for development on Ubuntu 18.04.

Since Ubuntu considers files with names starting with a period(.), hidden, I can not get the ".project" file accessed by Eclipse and the *import* fails. The error message I get is:

**Could not finish import job for Bnd Workspace!
The project description file (.project) for 'cnf' is missing.  This file contains important information about the project.  The project will not function properly until this file is restored.
The project description file (.project) for 'cnf' is missing.  This file contains important information about the project.  The project will not function properly until this file is restored.**

So, is there any way, **a software can access** hidden files in Ubuntu? OR in anyway those files can be made visible without changing their names?

Thanks in anticipation!

PS: I have tried "ls -a", "Ctrl+H" etc. but unfortunately none of these make the file accessible by any other software (Eclipse particularly).

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by _import_. There are many ways to import and it seems you choose the wrong one. In your case,  either in the _Git Repositories_ view right-click the cloned repository and choose _Import Projects..._ or use _File > Open Projects from File System..._.

Comment: By *import*, I mean to say, File -> Import -> Bndtools -> Existing bnd workspace, and then open [this](https://github.com/OpenEMS/openems) cloned repository. Wherein, cnf -> .project is inaccessible by Eclipse and it shows the aforementioned error.

Comment: I doubt that the `.project` file is inaccessible by Eclipse. If that would be the case, it would be due to the file permissions, not because it's a dotfile. Show whether the file is visible in the _Git Repositories_ view, below the _Working Tree_ node of the cloned repository.

Comment: Yes, you are right, it is inaccessible by the Eclipse. But, the file is visible in the tree and the directory has all the access (777).

Comment: If you can't see the `.project` file in the _Git Repositories_ view (please share a screenshot of it), does hitting the _Refresh_ button make it visible in Eclipse in the _Git Repositories_ view?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing special about dotfiles. You can access dotfiles by usual means just fine. Try this in a shell

```
~/ % echo "Hello" > /tmp/.hello.txt
~/ % cat /tmp/.hello.txt
Hello
```

You see, no problem. The fact that dotfiles are "hidden" is a legacy artifact from the early beginnings of Unix: When the `ls` tool was written, the authors wanted it to omit the special directory entries `.` (= current directory) and `..` (= parent directory), and they did this by simply checking of the name starts with a `.`; that's all that there is to "hiding" a file in Linux.

What more likely is, that you did improperly clone the Git repository or somehow else dropped the dotfiles. Use `ls -a` in the project directory to see *all* the files, and check, that `.project`, and the other dotfiles are actually there.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

You are very right! My bad, I did not mention. Actually, I can see the hidden files and as you said they are definitely there! but I wanted ask for a way that the software "Eclipse" can also see and read the hidden, ".project" file.

Comment: @bhutto Eclipse sees and reads hidden dotfiles. You just misread the error message.

Comment: can you please help me!
Actually what I am doing is:
 File -> Import -> Bndtools -> Existing bnd workspace, and then opening [this](https://github.com/OpenEMS/openems) cloned repository. Wherein, cnf -> .project is inaccessible by Eclipse and it shows the aforementioned error.

Comment: @bhutto can you put the output of `ls -la <your project directory>` into your original question?